# react native ScrollView not scrolling without any errors

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}>
    {pastGuesses.map((guess, index) => renderListItem(guess, pastGuesses.length - index))}
    </ScrollView>



    listContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '80%'
    },
    list: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    },
    listItem: {
        borderColor: "#ccc",
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 15,
        marginVertical: 10,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        width: "60%"
    }
```

Here i am using ScrollView in react native.
Here is my code shered. But, unfortunately the scroll is not working.
I am not getting any error but scorll is not happening.

Please take a look

Comment: You should set the height of your scrollview, otherwise the scrollview will become as long as the content inside it, thus the container not 'needing' to scroll inside it

Comment: That doesn't work. Tried now

Comment: We will need some more info about the elements surrounding the scrollView then

Comment: Have you tried using a Flatlist component ? Its a better way to render scrollable UI components instead of using map in scrollview.